# How to load multiple items in ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, svg

I'm trying to call different external SVG in a single HTML page. If I stick to one, everything works perfectly. As soon as I want to call different SVG sprites, I end up with only one loading. So basically, it loads only one sprite and ignores others. Am I missing something in the syntax here?

I'm using the following ajax code //I'm a newbie, so I'm sure that I'm making a terrible mistake here :)

```
<script>
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "sprite1", "sprite2", "sprite3", true);
ajax.send();
ajax.onload = function(e) {
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHtml = ajax.responseText;
document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>
```

Then in HTML I am using this

```
<svg class="sprite1">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-name">
</svg>
```

Comment: You can execute request in loop have a collection of Urls and then iterate it in for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XMLHttpRequest.open()` method can only accept [one URL](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp), so you need a separate request for each sprite. Try like this:

```
var sprites = ["sprite1", "sprite2", "sprite3"];

sprites.foreach(function(sprite, index) {
   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajax.open("GET", sprite, true);
   ajax.send();
   ajax.onload = function(e) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHtml = ajax.responseText;
      document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.childNodes[0]);
   };
});
```

Be aware that the order in which the sprites are returned cannot be guaranteed, so you may wish to load each one to a specific element in the HTML. You can use the `index` in the example to determine which has been loaded.